# how to show and hide buttons in listView

Tags: android, android-listview

As shown in the image when I click on an item in the list view. Buttons show up.

I want to hide buttons when I click on different items and show on current clicked item.

How can I make it work?

[image]

Comment: Please don't share your code as image always share your code as **`TEXT`**

Answer (score 0):

Need to preserve view into a variable like prevView. and then click on another item.

Check whether prevView is null or not. If not null. then get button id .
e.g. prevView.findViewById();

and Make their visibility.GONE. and also null prevView.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by making a model class.
take variable for particular buttons in Model. after clicking on a different item set `true/false` tag in the model and `show/hide` view according to that tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using an expandable ListView so that you can get the buttons shown when you tap on the list item and it get closed when you tap on the other item in the list.